# 2nd Point of Sector that lies on Circle on a 2D coordinate plane?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

Hey can anyone help in finding the second coordinate of sector that lies on circle.

I have a circle of radius 10 units, centred at (0,0). I am parting a sector of angle theta(sector can be minor or major). I have coordinate of First points of sector that lie on circle wanna find other points.

How to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use polar coordinates, then

- $x=R\sin \theta$
- $y=R\cos \theta$

indeed for

- $\theta=0$ we have the point $(0,R)$
- $\theta=\pi/2$ we have the point $(R,0)$

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, it helped me.